# How can I initialize a companion object property with a value taken from application.properties?

Tags: kotlin, initialization, lazy-initialization, application.properties, companion-object

Is it possible to initialize a property of a companion object with some value read from `application.properties`?

I tried

```
// @Value("\${my.property.value}") ...doesn't work
val myProp: Duration by lazy { Duration.ofMinutes(@Value("\${my.property.value}")) }
```

but IntelliJ complains: `Expecting an element`.
Okay Duration.ofMinutes() requires a Long not a String but how can I achieve this using a configurable value in application.properties?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but I'm curious as to why you'd want to do this.  In Spring, `@‍‍Service` &c classes are singletons anyway, so there's no point in giving them companion objects.  And you can autowire an instance of them and access a `@‍‍‍Value` property that way.

Comment: Is this companion object managed by spring?

Comment: You cannot do this as companion objects sort of behave like static variables. But then my question is what are you trying to solve by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the @Value annotation in a service class now.
My intention was to have this value read in into a single place near the entity.

Comment: This would be a better response with example code.